# Connection timed out on port 443 with AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install pritunl on an AWS instance. I run the following command:

`sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

And then it says this:

`Retrieving https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
curl: (7) Failed to connect to dl.fedoraproject.org port 443: Connection timed out
error: skipping https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm - transfer failed`

It is an Amazon Linux 2 instance.

I currently have HTTPS port 443 open to all inbound and outbound traffic in the security group. I don't know what's going on here, but can somebody please help? I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

Comment: There are many possibilities. Check the ACL and Route Table. If you have created the instance using the 'default' settings, then it should work. Not directly related but just to check : are you connecting into the instance using ssh via the internet?

Comment: Yes, using ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your EC2 instance may be in a private subnet instead of a public subnet. Check that.

If that indeed is the case then you will need to provision a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat.html)

> NAT device enables instances in a private subnet to connect to the Internet (for example, for software updates) or other AWS services, but prevent the Internet from initiating connections with the instances. A NAT device forwards traffic from the instances in the private subnet to the Internet or other AWS services, and then sends the response back to the instances.

Comment: Even the server is in private subnet, it will not be accesible via a URL, unless setup behind a internet-facing loadbalancer.

Comment: Yes, but not sure if that is a requirement at all based on the question